# How to join on timestamp in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. One has 4 days worth of data while other one has 2 days. Dataframe one looks like this
[image]

while df2 looks like this:
[image]

I need to join these. There are two options for joining these. First join based on dates that are existent in both. Second

I am merging them like this:
[image]

using this code:

```
pd.merge(freq_df_two,freq_df_one, on=["date","hour"])
```

Issue is that if the date from df1 is not present in df2 then it simply drops it. Forexample as you can see it doesnt have 2020-09-02. I want it to display NaN or 0 if that date and hour is not present in second df. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add `how='outer'` to your merge:

`pd.merge(freq_df_two,freq_df_one, on=["date","hour"], how='outer')`

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `merge` function by default uses the [inner strategy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) when merging, similar to [INNER JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) in sql. Meaning if the data is not present in the second one then its simply dropped. You should use the left strategy to merge, similar to [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

```
pd.merge(freq_df_two,freq_df_one, on=["date","hour"], how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can specify a `how` parameter.
Here `outer` is the equivalent of the SQL `full outer join`

```
pd.merge(freq_df_two,freq_df_one, on=["date","hour"], how="outer")
```

More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)